# CSS vertical align of inline-block not working

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id='inner'>I am sam <em>I am em</em> I am sam</div>
```

CSS:

```
#inner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: cyan;
}

em {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cbukkt3m/1/

Why does it throw the surrounding text to the top and not the em itself?

Comment: use `display: block;`

Comment: Depending on what you are hoping for you may also want `text-align: top;` instead of `vertical-align`

Comment: The `line-height` of `#inner` remains intact, but `em` is now padded at the top by `1em`. The `vertical-align: top;` is working, but the padding is counteracting it. Try setting `line-height` on the parent and `line-height: inherit;` on the `em`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is aligned to the top, it's being pushed down by:

```
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
```

try removing these or changing them to

```
margin: 0 1em;
padding: 0 1em;
```

Comment: Ha! after some though I now understand why. Thanks!